# Adding text label

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

how can I for every circle add text label? I mean I want to rotate this text, change color and something like this? I want to get solution without json, I want to get this data from

```js
var w = 300,
  h = 300;

var data = {
  name: "root",
  children: [{
      name: '1',
      size: 70
    },
    {
      name: '2',
      size: 90
    },
    {
      name: '3',
      size: 70
    },
    {
      name: '4',
      size: 40
    },
    {
      name: '5',
      size: 70
    },
    {
      name: '6',
      size: 20
    },
    {
      name: '7',
      size: 70
    },
  ]
}

var canvas = d3.select("#canvas")
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr('width', w)
  .attr('height', h);

var nodes = d3.layout.pack()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.size;
  })
  .size([w, h])
  .nodes(data);

// Get rid of root node
nodes.shift();

canvas.selectAll('circles')
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append('svg:circle')
  .attr('cx', function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr('cy', function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr('r', function(d) {
    return d.r;
  })
  .attr('fill', 'white')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .attr('width', 6)
  .attr('height', 6);

var textLabels = text
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.cx;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.cy;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "( " + d.cx + ", " + d.cy + " )";
  })
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "20px")
  .attr("fill", "red");
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>


<div id="canvas"></div>
```

I trying a lot of things but doesn't work antything..

Comment: what do you mean by _solution without json_

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by "without json", but I fixed your text labels.

You were in your code above calling `text` which was not defined, I think you intended to append it here.

You needed create a placeholder for the `text` label, iterate through the data again and then append the text.

```
canvas.selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return "( " + d.x + ", " + d.y + " )";
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "10px")
  .attr("color", "black");
```